# Set autocommit off at doctrine config level

Tags: php, doctrine, phpunit

I am aware that I can switch this off at mysql level as part of its config. This is limiting as its once per instance, and I dont want to switch on and off/introduce docker to circumvent it.

However, I would like to specify this at configuration level, ie in the array that you pass to doctrine when instantiating the object, so I can have one config that rolls every back at the end of the PHP run:

```
  $conn = array(
  'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
  'path' => __DIR__ . '/db.sqlite',
  'autocommit' => false // <- Does this exist?
);

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

The best I can come up with is to grab the entity manager and switch autocommit off in the `setUp()` and `tearDown()` functions, it would be nice to not to have to remember to do that or specify globally. That, and I can do ad-hoc operations outside of phpunit and get the auto rollback.

Comment: $this->em->getConnection()->setAutoCommit(false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not tested, but you could try the following

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:dogsDb_PDO.sqlite', $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT => false
));

$config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
$connectionParams = array(
    'dbname' => 'mydb',
    'user' => 'user',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'pdo' => $db,
);
$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

Source / simillar issue - https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2315

Comment: I never thought of this but since my config is actually a php file this could be the way to go, Ill test tomorrow.

Comment: TTTTTTThank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: $this->em->getConnection()->setAutoCommit(false);

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
/** @var EntityManagerInterface */
private $em;

public function setUp()
{
   // initialize the entity manager in some manner .....
   $this->em->beginTransaction();
}


public function tearDown()
{
   $this->em->rollback();
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is what I am currently doing of a fashion as outlined in the question

Comment: The visibility of `setUp()` and `tearDown()` on the parent class is `protected`. There is no need to increase it.

Comment: $this->em->getConnection()->setAutoCommit(false);